# GET Request for Users Salesforce.com Status (Integrated / Not)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

As the title says, I'm wondering if anyone knows the URL to query if a user is Integrated with SF in MC or not?

I thought maybe I could find that info with "platform/v1/accounts/{mid}/users" but its just returned some basic info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint you are referring to is unofficial and undocumented, so I wouldn’t depend on using it in a production setup.

User info is available through SOAP API, but unfortunately there are no objects that hold the information about Salesforce integration status.

Below is a list of all information queryable from the SOAP object **AccountUser**:

> AccountUserID - Specifies the Marketing Cloud identifier of an account
> user
>
> ActiveFlag    - Specifies the status of an account user
>
> AssociatedBusinessUnits   -   Indicates the business units the account
> user is associated with and can access. This property is
> non-retrievable.
>
> BusinessUnit  -   Specifies the account identifier of the business unit
>
> ChallengeAnswer   -   Specifies the challenge answer for login assistance
>
> ChallengePhrase   -   Specifies the challenge answer for login assistance
>
> Client    -   Specifies the account ownership and context of an object.
>
> CorrelationID -   Identifies correlation of objects across several
> requests.
>
> CreatedDate   -   Read-only date and time of the object's creation.
>
> CustomerKey   -   User-supplied unique identifier for an object within an
> object type. This property corresponds to the external key assigned to
> an object in Marketing Cloud.
>
> DefautApplication -   Specifies app the account user initially accesses
>
> DefaultBusinessUnit   -   Indicates that business unit account user
> initially accesses
>
> DefaultBusinessUnitObject -   Specifies the default business unit for a
> user.
>
> Delete    -   Indicates whether an object gets deleted.
>
> Email -   Default email address for object. Indicates if subscriber
> information can be used for email sends.
>
> ID    -   Read-only identifier for an object. Some objects use the ObjectID
> property as the Marketing Cloud unique ID.
>
> IsAPIUser -   Indicates if a user can use the API. A value of true
> indicates that the user's password remains the same until actively
> changed.
>
> IsLocked  -   Indicates if account user can or cannot log into their
> account LanguageLocale    Locale  Defines language preferences associated
> with a account, business unit, or user.
>
> LastSuccessfulLogin   -   Indicates data and time user last successfully
> logged in (read-only). Locale Locale  Contains the locale information
> for an Account. If no location is set, Locale defaults to en-US.
>
> ModifiedDate  -   Indicates the last time object information was
> modified.
>
> MustChangePassword    -   Indicates whether user must change password on
> next login
>
> Name  -   Name of the object or property.
>
> NotificationEmailAddress  -   Indicates email address to which to send
> notifications
>
> ObjectID  -   System-controlled, read-only text string identifier for
> object.
>
> Owner -   Describes account ownership of subscriber in an on-your-behalf
> account.
>
> PartnerKey    -   Unique identifier provided by partner for an object. This
> property is accessible only via API.
>
> PartnerProperties -   A collection of metadata supplied by the client
> and stored by the system. These properties are accessible only via
> API.
>
> Password  -   Property definition.
>
> Roles -   Collection of roles defined for an account.
>
> SsoIdentities -   Identifies single sign-on identities associated with
> the account user.
>
> TimeZone  -   Contains time zone information for an Account. For Create
> and Update calls, this property defines the time zone for an Account
> object. On a Retrieve call, TimeZone indicates which time zone is in
> effect for the Account object in question. Without a specific time
> zone, the Account defaults to Central Standard Time.
>
> Unlock    -   Indicates whether user gets unlocked
>
> UserID    -   Indicates username for an account.
>
> UserPermissions   -   For internal use only

See more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html

Comment: Ah, that's very disappointing! Thanks anyway